# Python Send reply to an gmail fails: A connection attempt failed because

Tags: python, email

Python sending a reply to an existing email in a gmail account fails with this error:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not     
properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

I have an email in my gmail account sent by an automation entity. With my python code, I receive its UID and try to reply to that, but it fails.

I read several stackoverflow posts on gmail reply and even read the https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#appendix-A.2 and [Gmail Send Email As Reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39276486/gmail-send-email-as-reply)

```
# An automation entity (abc@myNet.email.com) sends an email to my gmail Account xyz@gmail.com 
    
    from: abc@myNet.email.com  
    to: xyz@gmail.com        
    date: Jan 3, 2019, 7:19 AM 
    subject: abc Email Automation (Id=100) 
    security:  No encryption Learn more 

#Using IMAP4 I retrieve the UID of the last email with a given subject ("abc Email Automation"), 
    say --> 904

 # In python gmail reply 
    message = "I received your email"
    to_email = "abc@myNet.email.com "
    servername = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    username = "xyz@gmail.com"
    password = "blahblah"   # This is password to xyz@gmail.com

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = "xyz@gmail.com"
    msg['To'] = "abc@myNet.email.com"
    msg['Subject'] = "Re: abc Email Automation (Id=100)"
    msg['In-Reply-To'] = 904
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message))
    server = smtplib.SMTP(servername)
    try:
        server.set_debuglevel(True)
        server.ehlo()
        if server.has_extn('STARTTLS'):
            server.starttls()
            server.ehlo()  # re-identify ourselves over TLS connection

        server.login(username, password)
        server.sendmail(username, [to_email], msg.as_string())
    finally:
        print ("Can not send reply email")
        server.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would bet you have the port wrong.  https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en gives you the port to use - you're using TLS atop SMTP, not SSL I think ( I know, it's confusing :P) so you should be setting port 587.

```
server = smtplib.SMTP(servername, 587)
```

Comment: Thanks I tried:         try:
            server = smtplib.SMTP(servername, 587)
            server.set_debuglevel(True)
            server.ehlo()
            if server.has_extn('STARTTLS'):
                server.starttls()
                server.ehlo()  # re-identify ourselves over TLS connection

            server.login(username, password)
            server.sendmail(username, [to_email], msg.as_string())     still getting the same error

Comment: Thanks Dan.. I managed to get  it working, you were right.  This is what I did    gmail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
            gmail.ehlo()
            gmail.starttls()
            gmail.login("xyz@gmail.com", "blahblah")